# Is a comma needed after following in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, punctuation, commas

"Smallpox was declared eradicated in 1980 following a global immunization campaign."

Comment: Certainly not *after* "following".  Some people would put one before "following", but many would not.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean "before" **following**.
From THE CHICAGO MANUAL OF STYLE 6.30-6.31:
A dependent clause followed by a main clause should be followed by a comma.

**Following an immunization campaign, smallpox was declared eradicated in 1980.**

A dependent clause that follows the main clause should not be preceded by a comma if it is restrictive, that is, essential to the meaning of the main clause.

**Smallpox was declared eradicated in 1980 following a global immunization campaign.**

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If the question is as broad as "What were the circumstances of smallpox's eradication?" then, no, no comma is needed because all of the information is germane. If the questions is "What year was smallpox eradicated?" then a comma following "1980" is correct, because everything after that is information additional to what was sought. If the question is "What led to smallpox being declared eradicated?" then the proper answer is, "Smallpox was declared eradicated, in 1980, following a global immunization campaign," because the year is additional information. It's all a matter of perspective--what information is essential, which isn't. Only that which is non-essential takes a comma

Comment: Read it again.  He said "after *following*".

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant before following.

Comment: I like your answer, but the last sentence ( _Only that which is non-essential takes a comma_ ) is way too much generalization.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you're right. I only meant to lay out three ways to look at this particular sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of case's according to the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/comma#commas_to_mark_off_parts_of_a_sentence) which require a comma:

- in lists
- in direct speech
- to separate clauses
- to mark off certain parts of a sentence
- with 'however'

Since your sentence does not fall under any of these categories, a comma is not needed